# Bootup linux kernel profiling tool including kexec?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-9.10

Apart from OProfile, what tools do you recommend that I can use to profile my linux kernel while booting up?

I use kexec in Ubuntu server 9.04. OProfile doesn't seem to do the desired work for me, or at least I don't seem to be able to run it.

Any recomendation about a tool would be helpful, and if you know of a tool that can be used with kexec then that would be even better.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other tools that can be used to profile the kernel include:

- [Sysprof](http://sysprof.com/)
- [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/articles/t/u/t/Tutorial.html)
- [readprofile](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_readprofile.htm)

Also see [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/profiling/) for general information regarding profiling in Linux.

The boot process can be profiled using:

- [Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) an example of this is available [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/bootchart.html) This does everything after the kernel.
- [Printk Times](http://elinux.org/Printk_Times), this can be used to profile kernel bootup.
- [Kernel Function Trace](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Function_Trace),  this can be used to profile kernel bootup, though it has an approximate 30% overhead.
- [Boot Probe](http://people.redhat.com/berrange/systemtap/bootprobe/), set of [System Tap](http://elinux.org/System_Tap)  scripts for boot time profiling
- Also see [Kernel Instrumentation](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Instrumentation)

Comment: I will look into them. I believe perf wouldn't work on my Ubuntu but I am not 100% sure. Apart from that, can any of these be used to profile the booting processes as well ? sorry I missed the booting issue in my original post.

Comment: Best to additional information to your existing question, rather than as comment.

Comment: Thank you :) I edited my post... Bootchart wouldn't profile the kernel files... It starts after init